# Can this approximation result for stochastic processes be modified.(p=1 instead of p=2)?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

In McKeans stochastic integrals from 1969 he proves this:

> You have a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, where
>   the filtration is based on a Brownian motion. Assume that $X_t$ is a
>   process that is jointly measurable ($\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes
>  \mathcal{F}$), and adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$, and also assume that
>   $P(\int_o^T X_t^2 dt<\infty)=1$, then there exists a sequence of simple
>   functions of the form
>   $K_t^n=\Sigma_{1}^{N(n)}\phi_j(\omega)\mathcal{X}_{[t_j,t_{j+1})}$
>   ,where the simple functions satisfies adaptedness, joint-measurability
>   and the same integrability requirement as $X_t$. And we also have that
>   $P(\int_o^T(X_t-K_t^n)^2dt\,\,\,\,\,\, \overrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \,\,\,\,\,\,0)=1$.

I am wondering if where I wrote $X_t^2$ and $(X_t-K_t^n)^2$, I could have written $|X_t|$ and $|X_t-K_t^n|$, does the statement of the theorem still hold?

I don't really understand the proof, so I am not able to generalize it, or see if it would work if p=1. Do you know?

I think it would follow from the above theorem if we had that if $f_n,f$ is positive, integrable and $\int_0^T|\sqrt{f_n(t)}-\sqrt{f(t)}|^2dt \rightarrow 0$, then we also have that $\int_0^T |f_n(t)-f(t)|dt\rightarrow 0$, but I can't see if this holds either. Do you see if this one holds?

Comment: Is $T$ fixed in your context?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Yes

Comment: Do you assume that $(X_t)_t$ has continuous sample paths?

Comment: @saz No, I think it that were the case it would be very easy to show that it holds. We could just take the simple function at a point to be the process at the point, and I think then the convergence for each $\omega$ goes throgh very easily then. The proof in the book was very complicated, I don't think it would have been this complicated if the sample-paths were continuous.